# Git rebase when master has been changed

Tags: git, rebase

I created a branch `feat/add-access` from master, made a single change. Then I tried to rebase to master, but I realized changes have been made to master, so I got:

```
Your branch and 'origin/feat/add-access' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I removed my changes with:

```
 git fetch origin
 git reset --hard origin/master
 HEAD is now at 9cc1c2f Jenkins Pipeline PR Merger
```

HEAD is now at 9cc1c2f Jenkins Pipeline PR Merger

Which is OK, because `9cc1c2f` is the last commit on master. I also can see my changes has been removed.

Now I have:

```
project git:(feat/add-access) git status
On branch feat/add-access
Your branch and 'origin/feat/add-access' have diverged,
and have 2 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then I do:

```
➜  project git:(feat/add-access) git rebase master             
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feat/add-access.
```

But I still get diverging branches:

```
project git:(feat/add-access) git status
    On branch feat/add-access
    Your branch and 'origin/feat/add-access' have diverged,
    and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
      (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
    
    nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

git pull doesn't work.

```
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

`git log` shows no issue. In local, I am in the desired state, a copy of master branch.

I could simply delete remote feature branch, and just push it again, but I have an open PR on it, it may affect it, so I won't do it.

What should I do ? I'm a bit newbie with rebase, and I don't want to mess up the master branch !

Comment: Did you actually try `git pull`?  else, isn't there a difference when you do `git log` ?

Comment: git pull doesn't work. fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting. git log shows no issue. I could simply delete remote feature branch, and just push it again, but I have an open PR on it, it may affect it

Answer (score 0):

I think I could solve it, what I did was to rebase local feat branch changes into distant one with:

```
git rebase origin/feat/add-access feat/add-access
git push
```

and made a fixup to add my changes